# Is it cloaking to hide a <canvas> and display a message for mobile browsers?

Tags: seo, cloaking, canvas

I have a simple website with a single page containing a `canvas` element that is rendering a video game.

I have a script on this page that hides the `canvas` element and displays a special message when the site is rendered in a mobile browser.

**Will search engines penalize my website because it is rendering different content for different kinds of devices?**

Comment: Google has two crawlers, one for desktop and the other for mobile devices. Content that is visible for desktop will index for those devices, and vice versa. It's completely normal to use `display: none` and other friendly methods to hide content depending on the device.

Comment: make clear, that you hide things not based on defined user agents - this would be risky

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be okay, but to be sure give your users a link to the "desktop" version somewhere so nothing is cloaked.